# how to convert the given array using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
my @str = ("###jim","##word","<>","####idiot","#we","###jack","#e");

@array = ("hijim","dogword","parrot","iamidiot","aswe","hijack","ase");
```

by refering the str array i need ### to be converted to hi,## to be converted to dog,<> to be converted to parrot,#### to be converted to iam,# to be converted to we  and strored in @array

Comment: `s/(?| (#+)|(<>) )/$decode{$1}/x for my @array = @str;`

Comment: where i need to give hi dog parrot iam as

Comment: Put them into `%decode` hash.

Comment: can u please send me the program

Comment: Nope; make some effort, don't expect everything to be served to you.

Answer (score 0):

So I workout on your problem. Try the given solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @str = ("###jim","##word","<>","####idiot","#we","###jack","#e");

my @arr = ();

@arr = @str;

print "\@arr = @arr \n\n";  #original array

for(my $i=0;$i<$#str+1;$i++)
{
    $str[$i] =~ s/^####/iam/ if($str[$i] =~ /^####/);
    $str[$i] =~ s/^###/hi/ if($str[$i] =~ /^###/);
    $str[$i] =~ s/^##/dog/ if($str[$i] =~ /^##/);
    $str[$i] =~ s/^#/we/ if($str[$i] =~ /^#/);
    $str[$i] =~ s/^<>$/parrot/ if($str[$i] =~ /^<>$/);
}


print "\@str = @str\n\n";  #array after substitution
```

Here I used `substitute` of perl. First we will iterate through each and every element from array and then using substitute try to match the given pattern and if it match substitute the required value.

OUTPUT :

```
@arr = ###jim ##word <> ####idiot #we ###jack #e 
@str = hijim dogword parrot iamidiot wewe hijack wee
```